# How to tag corrupted data in dataframe after an error has been raised

Tags: python, pandas, error-handling

I have a large dataframe containing, amongst other things, a (Norwegian) social security number. It is possible to get the date of birth out of this number via a special algorithm. However, every now and then an illegal social security number creeps into the database corrupting the calculation.

What I would like to do is to tag every line having an illegal social security number, along with a log message showing the error raised.

Consider the following, constructed, example

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date

sample_data = pd.DataFrame({'id' : [1, 2, 3], \
                            'sec_num' : [19790116, 19480631, 19861220]})


# The actual algorithm transforming the sec number is more complicated
# this is just for illustration purposes
def int2date(argdate: int):

    try:
        year = int(argdate / 10000)
        month = int((argdate % 10000) / 100)
        day = int(argdate % 100)
        return date(year, month, day)
    except ValueError:
        raise ValueError("Value:{0} not a legal date.".format(argdate))
```

I want to create the following output

```
   id   sec_num date_of_birth  is_in_error                    error_msg
0   1  19790116    1979-01-16        False  
1   2  19480631          None         True 19480631 is not a legal date         
2   3  19861220    1986-12-20        False
```

I have tried

```
try:
    sample_data['date_of_birth'] = [int2date(sec_num) for \
                   sec_num in sample_data['sec_num']]
    sample_data['is_in_error'] = False
    sample_data['error_msg'] = ''
 except ValueError as e:
    sample_data['is_in_error'] = True
    sample_data['error_msg'] = str(e)
```

but this produces this

```
   id   sec_num  is_in_error                         error_msg
0   1  19790116         True  Value:19480631 not a legal date.
1   2  19480631         True  Value:19480631 not a legal date.
2   3  19861220         True  Value:19480631 not a legal date.
```

I guess the problem is that I assign the `date_of_birth`-column in one operation and the errors in another. I am not sure how to catch and create the `is_in_error` and `error_msg` columns simulationously.

Comment: Sorry can you post a realistic data sample and what your real algorithm actually is, currently even if this was a string 31st of June isn't a valid date anyway

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are asking for. The algorithm performs correctly, it creates a day, month and year variable and then it creates a date based on those values date(year, month, day). The problem occurs when an invalid social security number produces an illegal date. In this example I have just jumped directly to the illegal date.

Comment: Why don't you just do `df['date_of_birth'] = pd.to_datetime(df['sec_num'].astype(str), format='%Y%M%D'm errors='coerce')` this will place `NaT` where you have invalid dates. Also essentially what you're doing when you do `sample_data[some_col] = some_val` you're setting the entire column to that value rather than a specific row

Comment: Well ok i see why it would be valuable to input the whole algorithm... the actual social security number is something is 11 digits and you can't use pd.to_datetime on that. So i would first have to return a string or int from the algorithm, and then cast that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens because of the way you're populating the dataframe.

```
sample_data['error_msg'] = str(e)
```

Will actually overwrite the entire column with `str(e)`.

This is probably the most efficient way to do it:

```
def int2date(argdate: int):

    try:
        year = int(argdate / 10000)
        month = int((argdate % 10000) / 100)
        day = int(argdate % 100)
        return date(year, month, day)
    except ValueError as e:
        pass # you could write the row and the error to your logs here

df['date_of_birth'] = df.sec_num.apply(int2date)
df['is_in_error'] = df.date_of_birth.isnull()
```

However if you also want to write the errors to the dataframe, you can use this approach although it might be much slower (there might be faster solutions to this).

```
df['date_of_birth'] = None
df['error_msg'] = None
df['is_in_error'] = False
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    try:
        date_of_birth = int2date(row['sec_num'])
        df.set_value(i, 'date_of_birth', date_of_birth)
    except ValueError as e:
        df.set_value(i, 'is_in_error', True)
        df.set_value(i, 'error_msg', str(e))
```

This handles each row separately and will only write the error to the correct index instead of updating the entire column.

Comment: Your second way is the recommended pandas approach (function+apply).  The first way is kind of OK but will be very slow (also you need to capitalize true & false).  Generally speaking you want to avoid iterrows except as an absolute last resort.  If you are so inclined, I would  recommend deleting the top half of the answer and keeping the bottom half.

Comment: Just an observation, regarding the second part of your answer, in Effective Python (for those having a copy of that book lying about) it states that returning `None` is bad form. This bugs me a bit, because JohnE's comment is also true :|

Comment: Thanks @JohnE for the input, I changed the answer accordingly.
I also change the function to not return `None`.

Answer (score 2):

You are in the realm of handling large data.  Throwing exceptions out of a loop is often not the best idea there because it will normally abort the loop.  As many others you do not seem to want that.

To achieve that a typical approach is to use a function which does not *throw* the exception but which *returns* it instead.

```
def int2date(argdate: int):
    try:
        year = int(argdate / 10000)
        month = int((argdate % 10000) / 100)
        day = int(argdate % 100)
        return date(year, month, day)
    except ValueError:
        return ValueError("Value:{0} not a legal date.".format(argdate))
```

With this you simply can map a list of values to the function and will receive the exceptions (which lack a trace of course, but in such a case this should not be a problem) as values in the result list:

You then can walk over the list, replace the found exceptions by `None` values and fill other columns instead with the message contained in the exception.